# Eclipse Dependency is not in pom.xml but still under "Maven Dependencies" group

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I added a dependency using Maven to my Java project in Eclipse. I added one version of the dependency from repository, then I saw that version is not what I want, then added an higher version (that doesn't exist in repositories) manually using maven's commands. And finally I deleted the older version from pom.xml, and added the new version to there. I used following command to add newer version to repo:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=PATH_OF_JAR -DgroupId=GROUP_ID -DartifactId=ARTIFACT_ID -Dversion=VERSION -Dpackaging=jar
```

Now the problem is that older version remains in "Maven Dependencies" group. And my code part using that dependency jar won't see the new version. I deleted manually the older version from Maven local repo, and also executed the "purge" command of Maven. Every time I update, the older version keeps coming back. How do I make my project just see the newer version and completely get rid of the older version?

The pom.xml entry is as following (which points the new version, the version I desire):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jface</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.jface</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What did you exactly do when you _added an higher version (that doesn't exist in repositories) manually using maven's commands._? If you did not install the new version into the repository Maven will fall back to the old version. You can even "force" to use the new version if you put the version number in breaks like `<version>[1.2.3]</version]`.

Comment: Please show us your pom.xml file with dependency

Comment: I added pom.xml entry, please check.

Comment: Does the artifactId is correctly defined?Do you have some error mark in eclipse for pom.xml?

Comment: If you use eclipse that have a look at the "Dependency Hierarchy" tab of the pom.xml viewer. Click at the org.eclipse.jface on the resolved dependencies tab and see where it comes from (maybe your version is overruled by a transitive dependency).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Older version is called in another dependency. Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like another dependency  is bringing it in... Do a maven dependency tree to resolve your conflicts. [See apache's guide here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=YOUR_OLD_DEPENDENCY
```

You may also use tools to aid this such as your IDE

Intelli-j

- right click > Maven --> Show Dependency
- shortcut : ctrl + alt + shift + u

Eclipse

- click on the pom's "dependency hierarchy" tab suggested by @FrVaBe bellow

Comment: Nice answer. Was not aware of the `includes` property so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you use eclipse than have a look at the "Dependency Hierarchy" tab of the pom.xml viewer. Click at the `org.eclipse.jface` artifact on the resolved dependencies tab and see where it comes from (maybe your version is overruled by a transitive dependency).

This answer is quite similar to @MMans answer (+1 for this) - just using other tools that might be easier to use than the command line (for some) ;-)